# how to switching from speaker and earpiace during audio play

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i need to implement a switch function to change from speaker and earpiace

i used this code to play in earpiace

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://***.mp3"));
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

if use `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` instead of `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` works with speaker. but if i switch rintime there is no changes. this is my code

```
int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: `setAudioStreamType` is deprecated. You shoud use `setAudioAttributes` instead. Neither of them are effective after the call to `prepare` or `prepareAsync`.

Comment: One possibility, now that I think about it, is to call `reset` after you call `stop`. It may be that simple.

Comment: about setAudioStreamType deprecation: which is te correct way to do this thing compatible prior 21 api lev?

Comment: If you need to support APIs prior to 21, then use `setAudioStreamType`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
mediaPlayer.stop();
// The next two lines are added to your original code
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://***.mp3"));
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: it worked but in this way i download file every time i switch stream type. there is no better way?

Comment: Just using the `MediaPlayer`, no, not really. Not without a lot of work. You can download the file prior to playback, then play from the local file.